# The system cannot find the file specified when using the command "meteor npm install"

Tags: node.js, npm

```
> botfront@0.25.0-rc.1 postinstall c:\botfront\botfront
> copy -R node_modules/semantic-ui-css/themes/default/assets/fonts ./public/ && copy -R node_modules/semantic-ui-css/themes/default/assets/fonts ./client/

The system cannot find the file specified.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! botfront@0.25.0-rc.1 postinstall: `copy -R node_modules/semantic-ui-css/themes/default/assets/fonts ./public/ && copy -R node_modules/semantic-ui-css/themes/default/assets/fonts ./client/`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the botfront@0.25.0-rc.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

This is the error i am getting

Comment: `copy -R` is not valid syntax in Windows' command shell. Looks like someone just replaced `cp` with `copy` and expected it to work. Possibly `botfront` doesn't work with Windows, you could try whether it works in WSL instead.

Comment: When trying with copy,, it says > botfront@0.25.0-rc.1 postinstall c:\botfront\botfront
> copy /node_modules/semantic-ui-css/themes/default/assets/fonts ./public/ && copy /node_modules/semantic-ui-css/themes/default/assets/fonts ./client/

The syntax of the command is incorrect.

Comment: Yes because it's still not a valid copy command like that: Windows' copy works differently than Linux' cp. As I said, it doesn't work with Windows! Try running it in WSL or on a Linux box... You could remove the postinstall and manually copy those files (or use xcopy with the right arguments) but it seems this package was never tested with Windows so I'd assume you'd run into other issues too. (maybe open an issue at their GitHub)